# Get pose of pr2 from gazebo

Tags: gazebo, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I launch the pr2 in gazebo, I see that gazebo keeps track of its pose.
How do I get this pose programmatically?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59920/get-pose-of-pr2-from-gazebo/) by [kachilous](https://answers.ros.org/users/2437/kachilous/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can write a client to the [get_joint_properties](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gazebo) service and request the joint state.

See also here:
http://answers.ros.org/question/43157/trying-to-use-get-joint-state-with-my-urdf/

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0